# ¿Como pasar un proyecto local hecho con Gradle a otra computadora?

Tags: java, gradle

No sé si me explico en mi pregunta. Va de nuevo:

Tengo hecha una pagina web con el Framework Spring MVC y tuve que usar Gradle para el manejo de las dependencias (porque estuve siguiendo un curso) de Spring y Spring Boot. También las de ThymeLeaf (que es una especie de Angular JS para el Front-End).

Es mi primera vez usando Gradle y Spring y no me queda muy claro como es el tema para correr este proyecto en una maquina que no sea la mía.

El IDE utilizado es IntelliJ Community (no sé si aporta en algo).

Osea, yo desde mi IDE levanto el proyecto con el bootRun y luego accedo a mi localHost como con casi todas las web.

Necesito llevar este proyecto a una computadora (de la facultad) que tiene Windows (la mía es Linux) y levantarlo en un Eclipse. Estuve intentando en mi propia maquina y no pude, así que supongo tendré el mismo inconveniente en la otra compu.

Alguien me puede explicar como funciona Gradle para con estas cosas ... ¿ Simplemente debo comprimir mi proyecto e importarlo en otro IDE o debo levantarlo en otro IDE con algun comando especial, o como es ?

Desde el IntelliJ por ejemplo, cuando creo un nuevo proyecto Java me da la opción de Gradle, pero en Eclipse no la ví.

Necesito disipar mis dudas, muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

Bueno gradle es un constructor de builds y manejador de dependencias para Java. 
IntelliJ, NetBeans, Eclipse son IDEs que tienen un plugin de gradle para levantar el proyecto creado. 
Por debajo lo que hace cada IDE básicamente es ejecutar el Gradle con sus tareas en este caso es **gradle bootRun** tiene otros como gradle clean build  y otros. Puedes levantar con cualquier IDE tu proyecto siempre y cuando instales o tenga el plugin de gradle agregado. Ahora si lo quieres hacer correr manualmente por cmd Windows o terminal linux. Debes descargar e instalar Gradle https://gradle.org una vez instalado entras hasta el directorio raíz de tu proyecto y ejecutas. gradle clean build bootRun estas tareas para que puedas levantar tu proyecto sin necesidad de algún IDE. 
Saludos.